# why do I get a § instead of a `

Tags: keyboard

my keyboards has a button that looks like this:
[image]

when I press it instead of the depicted `, i get the sign: §
any ideas?

Comment: Check your keyboard layout in system preferences > keyboard > input sources.

Comment: Also, what keyboard type is it? Is that key next to the 1 key or next to the Z key? [post a picture of it if you're not sure what type it is.]

Comment: Does your key to the right of left shift produce what that button shows?

Comment: Your machine may think your keyboard is of the wrong "type".  Some possible fixes are at  https://m10lmac.blogspot.com/2009/12/fixing-keyboard-type-problems.html